# Join суммы за период

Tags: mysql, join

В первой таблице формат:
id и Дата уникальные значения.

Во второй таблице:
id, дата, сумма.

Как можно сформировать таблице формата:
id, дата, сумма за последние 12 месяцев от даты из первой таблицы?

Например:
table_1

```
id  date
1   01.01.2001
```

table_2

```
id   date          amount
1    12.12.2000    100
1    07.05.2000    100
1    01.12.1999    100
```

Должно получиться:

```
id   date          amount
1    01.01.2001    200
```

думал что-то такое, но увы

```
select t1.id, t1.date, sum(2.amount)
from table_1 t1 
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.date>=dateadd(year, -12, t2.date)
```

Comment: Пример данных предоставили бы хоть

Comment: @OwDafuq дополнил

Comment: добавьте алиасы в селект, ограничьте условия на дату с обоих сторон, добавьте группировку и должно заработать вроде

Comment: Какой у вас формат даты - просто строка?

Comment: в join'e поменяйте второе условие на: `t2.date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, t1.date) AND t1.date` и еще `GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date`

Comment: Если дата хранится именно в таком виде - это не дата, а обычная строка. Соответственно требуется ещё преобразовать её в дату функцией STR_TO_DATE(). Хотя правильнее - изменить тип поля.

Comment: @Akina мб выводится так в зависимости от настроек локали пользователя в системе?

Comment: @teran MySQL чхать хотел на локаль клиента. Это сам клиент может организовать такой "сервис".

Comment: @Akina ну так кто его знает, откуда вывод скопирован.

Comment: @OwDafuq помогло в решении, спасибо